# Get stream of data from DB | Sembast | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sembast

I'm working with Sembast nowadays and was wondering If there's any way to create a stream of data that could get me all the values inside the DB. My requirement is to setup a listener on that stream so that whenever the data change is triggered, I could do something with it.

Documentation on Sembast is pretty limited and I'm now sure how I can do this. Usually I use the `.find` method to fetch all the values from within my db. I've been using a `stringMapFactory` to store my records.

Can we do this ? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the poor documentation.

It is quite similar to firestore. You can listen to all changes in a store

```dart
// Track every store changes
var query = store.query();
var subscription = query.onSnapshots(db).listen((snapshots) {
  // snapshots always contains the list of all records

  // ...
});
```

Basically you have a query on the store (with or without filter) that you can query or listen for changes.

- See https://pub.dev/documentation/sembast/latest/sembast/QueryRef/onSnapshots.html
- https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/blob/master/sembast/doc/change_listener.md

Answer (score -1):

If you use Hive as db, may use Hive Box as listenable.

```
ValueListenableBuilder<Box<YOUR_BOX_MODEL>>(
valueListenable: box.listenable(),
builder: (context,value,child){}
)
```